# Detect Up and Down Scolling but in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Website is only scrollbar in diffrent div. I put overscroll-y: auto in a div. Now i want to detect when i scroll down and when i scroll up. Normaly it would look like this:

```js
let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function () {
    let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-100px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};
```

```css
html,body{
margin:0;
background: blue;
height: 200vh;
}

#navbar{
position: fixed;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: red;
transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar"><p>Link</p> <div>
```

But now this all should happen in a seperate Div and not on the base auto implemented scroll on the window.

I need it to make my navbar disapeare when the User watches my Picture. It only should appear when you need it and you need it when you scroll back up.

PS: I only use Vanilla JS

Comment: Why not use the `onscroll` event directly on the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question then you want to scroll another element when you scroll something else. You should look into scrollTop you can set the scroll position of an element in JS with this property.

Comment: thx i could just replace all window with my element and pageYOffset with scrollTop and it worked!!! Thx